# Why is Excel not finding my system DSN when moving to Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, excel, odbc, vba

I have a VBA Excel workbook (2007) that works fine on my Windows XP 32-bit machine. It uses ODBC to connect to PostgreSQL via a system DSN. I recently moved to a 64-bit Windows 7 machine and installed drivers and built the system DSN the exact same yet I am not connecting.

I see lots of references to building DSNs with the 32-bit ODBC tool and I think I have done that. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

You are using the 64 bit ODBC connector with (I'm presuming) 32 bit Office.

Use the ODBC connector at `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe` instead of the one inside your control panel to setup the System DSN and it will work. You will need to right click and select `Run as Administrator`.